# How to find a value entered in a textbox in a <li> list in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, find

I have a group of values in a `<ul>` list and I want to search the value entered in a textbox to be highlighted in the `li` list. How can I do this?

Comment: Please add the HTML and JS code you have to the question.

Comment: Can we please have the code that you have written so far?

Comment: $("#find").click(function(){
var ss = $('#textval').val();
if($('.M_list').val() == $(ss).text()){
$(ss).css('background-color','yellow');
}
});

Comment: this is the one done so fare

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest solution would be:

```
var inputVal = $('input').val();
$('li:contains("'+inputVal+'")').css('background-color','#FF0000'); // or change any other CSS property to highlight
```

Comment: when I find the value in the li list the name is getting highlighted . if i want to search multiple values means that  highlighted part is still there in the outputscreen . so how do i remove the color from that

Comment: in that case, you should add/remove css class on `LI` instead of adding css properties. That would be easier.

Comment: it must find the value even if we give the values in lower or upper case. for that how to make them work that way

Answer (score 0):

```
$('li').each(function() {
  if($('input').val() == $(this).text()) {
     $(this).css('background-color','#ccc');
  }
});
```

Comment: even this will work but  this did not suit my application many any way thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try it, use keyup event on textbox :

```
$("input:text").on("keyup", function(){
  var val=$(this).val();
  $("li:contains('"+val+"'))").css('background-color','#ccc');
});
```

Comment: even this will work but  this did not suit my application many any way thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code
Html

```
<ul id="ull">
    <li>hi</li>
    <li>hello</li>
    <li>how</li>
</ul>
<input type="text" id="tt">
```

Jquery

```
$("#tt").change(function(){
  var val1=$(this).val();
   $("#ull li").each(function(){
       if( $(this).text()==val1){
           $(this).css("background-color", "yellow");
       }
   })

})
```

Comment: even this will work but  this did not suit my application many any way thanks